# Telegram бот на PHP: как отправить картинку и текст одним сообщением?

Tags: бот

Пишу бота на PHP без библиотек.
Понятно как отправить картинку и текст, но они приходят в бота двумя отдельными блоками:

```
$response = array(
    'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
    'photo' => curl_file_create(__DIR__ . '/image.jpg')
);  
sendit($response, 'sendPhoto');
```

```
$response = array(
    'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
    'text' => hex2bin('F09F9A80').' Your name: '.$data['message']['from']['first_name'].' '.$data['message']['from']['last_name'].' id:'.$data['message']['from']['id'].' date:'.$data['message']['date']); 
sendit($response, 'sendMessage');
```

Вопрос: как отправить картинку и подпись к ней в одном блоке?

UPD: решил

```
$response = array(
    'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
    'caption' => hex2bin('E29BAA').'This is a test text for the photo',
    'photo' => curl_file_create(__DIR__ . '/image.jpg')
);  
sendit($response, 'sendPhoto');
```